# In review queue, why don't I get all of the flag options?

Tags: discussion, review, flags, low-quality-posts

I was reviewing a question that only said "kkkk...kkkkkk" so I clicked "Recommend Close". However, it does not give me all of the options, and the ones listed aren't sufficient:

[image: flag choices]

The question was:

[image: original post]

Comment: "Unclear what you're asking" springs to mind ;)... but yes, I get your point.

Comment: @Matt Yeah, that is what I ended up going with but if you read the description of the "unclear" option, it doesn't seem to fit that even.

Comment: My LQP has "Recommend Deletion", not "Recommend Close".  Does the button text change based on some external criteria?  Or does it not give the delete option for questions?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but it's more likely that this is a case where rolling back a vandalism edit is required, rather than closing.

Comment: @CodyGray I noticed that, see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191515/169404) question that I posted right after this one. Previous edits are hidden while editing in the review queue, as is the rollback button, making it very hard for me to know it is vandalism (I didn't know until after).

Comment: @psubsee2003 You can only recommend deletion (or delete) on answers. This is a question, and needs to be closed before it can be deleted.