# While reviewing, why do I not get the option to see previous edits?

Tags: feature-request, review, low-quality-posts, edits, rollbacks

While reviewing low quality posts, I noticed a question that had been vandalized. I clicked edit so that I could do a rollback. However, there is no option to see the previous edits or rollback. I had to cancel the edit, leave the review queue, and go to the post itself just to do this.

Can we get this added? It is odd that it is not already there. Why would only *some* of the edit features be available in the review queue?

**EDIT:** The question that I was reviewing: [Rails Server/Bundle/gem Error on UBUNTU VM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18004379/938695)

Comment: It is probably because you are reviewing THAT edit, what do previous edits have to do with that one?

Comment: @JeremyBoyd Austin stated that because that question was vandalized, he needed to see previous edit history on that question to rollback.

Answer (score 1):

The rollback option isn't available from the inline editor on the normal question page either.  Nor is the list of previous revisions. Those only show up on the *full* edit page. So to answer your question, it's not available in /review because review queues use the inline editor.

[image: inline editor]

*Inline editor - no rollback option*

[image: full editor]

*Full editor - note the revision list*

Note that the rollback option is always available from the revision history, which is accessible from both the normal question page and review.

Not that the list of past revisions isn't handy on occasion, but... If your only goal is to *rollback* a vandalizing edit, why would you bother opening the editor at all?

Comment: I bothered opening the editor because when reviewing I am given the choices: "No Action Needed", ..., "Edit", "Skip". I clicked Edit. Which of those should I do instead?

Comment: How do I get to the full editor directly from a post? Clicking edit opens the inline editor.

Comment: @Austin: probably "close". If you really want to roll back, then you'd open the revision history in the normal fashion (by clicking the last modified date) - and then follow up with "looks good", if that actually fixed it.

Comment: Right-click edit, open in new window, @AsheeshR.

Comment: @Shog9 Is that mentioned *anywhere* in the Help Center?

Comment: @AsheeshR: the help center? Probably not - it's pretty obscure. You can find it discussed [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98132/new-way-to-edit-bug-where-are-the-previous-edits) though. Folks without full editing privileges also get it when [suggesting edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143897/rollback-option-only-available-when-suggesting-edits-not-when-you-have-full-edi) - however, they cannot rollback from the revision history.

Comment: [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191515/while-reviewing-why-do-i-not-get-the-option-to-see-previous-edits/191709?noredirect=1#comment596901_191709) could be mentioned [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) under "How do I edit posts". Its a useful feature even if its only needed once in while.